# How do I CSS transition a modal dialog element when it opens?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I want to apply a `transition` to dialog elements when they are opened, but my `transition` attribute doesn't seem to be having any effect. Here's my code:

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

document.querySelector("#open-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});
document.querySelector("#close-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in, background-color 2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in, background-color 2s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in, background-color 2s ease-in;
}

dialog[open] {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="open-button">Open Dialog Element</button>

<dialog>
  <button id="close-button">Close Dialog Element</button>
</dialog>
```

My intent is to slowly fade the dialog into view as its background visibly changes from red to green.

Instead, the rules of `dialog[open]` are immediately applied? [The MDN  article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) doesn't mention `transition`s or animations anywhere, implying this should work as any other element.

I am testing this in Firefox on Windows 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your dialog transitions from `display:none` to `display:block` and that ruins `transition`. The idea was to add `dialog { display:block; }` but it turned out bad because the dialog is just hidden and reacts to the keyboard TAB navigation for example... So we need to keep a closed dialog `display:none`.

So a couple of solutions:

1. You could use `animation` which I like since it's a pure CSS solution:

```
dialog[open] {
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:1;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

document.querySelector("#open-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});
document.querySelector("#close-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
}

dialog[open] {
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:1;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="open-button">Open Dialog Element</button>

<dialog>
  <button id="close-button">Close Dialog Element</button>
</dialog>
```

2. You could also add a CSS class after the opening with `setTimeout` to allow the DOM to be re-rendered and remove it on the closing with your `transition` left intact.

```
setTimeout(()=>dialog.classList.add('open'));
dialog.addEventListener('close', () => dialog.classList.remove('open'));
```

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

dialog.addEventListener('close', () => dialog.classList.remove('open'));

document.querySelector("#open-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
  setTimeout(()=>dialog.classList.add('open'));
});

document.querySelector("#close-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in, background-color 2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in, background-color 2s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in, background-color 2s ease-in;
}

dialog.open {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="open-button">Open Dialog Element</button>

<dialog>
  <button id="close-button">Close Dialog Element</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Any idea why `transition` doesn't do anything?

Comment: @DanielKaplan i didn't investigate it deep, but my understanding is a dialog's kinda REPRESENTATION doesn't exist before the opening, so it's not hidden, just doesn't exist. so when you open the dialog it's already created with `[open]` so there's no any transition to the open state thus `transition` doesn't work. on the other hand `animation` doesn't require the transition. you could make it with transition also. for that you should use a CSS class, which you assign after the opening.

Comment: @DanielKaplan i find `animation` better because you can actually use it on the closing! while using `transition` would require a custom event handling and hacky delaying of the closing

Comment: @DanielKaplan if my answer solves your problem don't hesitate to accept & upvote it, thanks

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense, but before I accept this answer I want to see if anyone can confirm this is the reason why you can't `transition`.

Comment: @DanielKaplan ok, finished, a final answer finally...